# How to change PC/laptop Screen brightness programmatically from windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am trying to change some computer settings from my metro app. Please tell a way to control Screen brightness programmatically from metro/windows store app.

I am developing my metro app using C#.

Comment: A store app runs in a sandbox that strictly limits what such an app can do.  "Change some computer settings" fall into that category, store apps are forbidden from tinkering with anything that affects the computer.  Either enforced by the sandbox or the necessary api simply missing, your case.  Nor does the user require your help to adjust screen brightness, it is readily available from the keyboard, the built-in power applet or a knob on the monitor.

Comment: This is not allowed in windows store apps It will not access any Settings Related to the global user Experience as it runs in a SandBox